# Python excel integration, #VALUE error

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have a working program which integrates python and Excel (thanks to xlwt). I am reading from a csv file and copying into an excel. While I do this, I also have a few formulae that I include using the formula module in xlwt. To be specific, the code is

```
ws_xlwt.write(3,3, Formula("MMULT(MINVERSE(C11:D12),"+col_char+"2:"+col_char+"3)"), style)
```

col_char is an ASCII code generated in the loop. The array (C11:D12) contains data generated using the code:

```
ws_xlwt.write(10,2, Formula("SUMPRODUCT($C$36:$C$161,$C$36:$C$161)"), style)
```

When the program runs, it puts the formula in the particular cell correctly. But the cell displays the error "#VALUE" instead of the result. The interesting point is when I open the excel file, double click on this particular cell to edit it and hit enter without changing anything, the result is displayed. I am not sure if this is a python integration issue or if its an Excel problem.

```
OS - Windows 7 64-bit
Python - 2.7 32-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that it is due to the evaluation of the formula. I don't believe that `xlwt` evaluates the formulas as they are inserted, meaning that you get a value error because the results of the `SUMPRODUCT` do not exist when the `MMULT` function is evaluated. The reason it works when you double-click and hit enter is because Excel is now recalculating everything, giving you a valid result.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too. So, I included

wb_xlwt.save(os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] +".xls") in between the sumproduct and the mmult.. 

ws_xlwt.write(10,2, Formula("SUMPRODUCT("+col_char+"36:"+col_char+"161,$O$36:$O$161)"), style)
   wb_xlwt.save(os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] +".xls")
   ws_xlwt.write(3,3, Formula("MMULT(MINVERSE(C11:D12),"+col_char+"2:"+col_char+"3)"), style)


This should effectively save the sheet and the book and then write to it again (I think) therefore eliminating the error. It still hasn't resolved the issue. 
so, in brief it now reads..

Comment: @groovyrv I don't think saving it will do the trick - you need to open it after you write the original formula in order to force Excel to calculate it (Excel needs to be involved because `xlwt` does not do any calculations itself).

Comment: @groovyrv Did a little more research, and it seems it is the case that you will need to open/close Excel in order for it to work. See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198365/facing-problem-with-xlwt-and-xlrd-reading-and-writing-simultaneously), where the author indicates that is the issue. You will either need to split the script into pieces, opening Excel as necessary; or programmatically open/close it.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I have been able to get it to work using openpyxl for now by directly putting the formula into the cell. Though I did figure out that I have a slightly bigger problem now (array formulae) which are not supported by any of the free excel readers. Maybe this question is for another thread. Thanks again.

Comment: @groovyrv No problem at all, happy to help. Ha, array formulas are definitely good times :) I'm sure you have a reason for writing the formulas to Excel (sharing with others, making dynamic modeling easier, etc.), but have you considered doing the calculations in Python and writing the flat results?

Comment: I have debated that thought too just that programmatically, letting excel calculate the results is going to much more efficient than python doing the calculations and then spitting the results out. At least that's what I think. But again, that's the way I might go if I can't figure out a tweak for using array formulae directly interfacing Python with Excel. I have a lot of data that is saved into a lot files with a proprietary extension and saved in a very messy way. Hence, Python to the rescue.

Comment: @groovyrv Yeah, I would definitely not underestimate Python when it comes to doing calculations. There are some situations (e.g. a COUNTIF on a range of 100K rows) where Excel will take minutes (if it doesn't crash) while Python can do the equivalent in seconds. Plus, if you just care about the resulting data and don't need the underlying formula, you will gain efficiency on the Excel side in the form of the workbook not automatically calculating the formulas you add each time you change something.

Comment: I haven't programmed enough in Python to know how much quicker it is compared to excel/any other language. I will give this a shot too and report back.

Comment: @groovyrv Awesome, good luck with everything - you may start to do everything in Python after you get more familiar with it, so be warned :)

Comment: numpy FTW! I got pretty much everything working in Python. It literally takes seconds! :) Now, on to plotting and fitting this data! and yes, I am starting to do EVERYTHING in python! Not complaining AT ALL!!

Comment: @groovyrv Now that is what I like to hear! Since you're numpy savvy, I'm sure you've come across matplotlib as well - the fun never ends! Happy to hear it is working out :)

Comment: I posted another question here though I never got a reply from anyone. I thought I might ask you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558411/optimizing-or-speeding-up-reading-from-xy-files-into-excel

Comment: @groovyrv Posted an answer (which you probably saw already, so me posting here is probably redundant :) ). Hope it helps!