# How to F9 Excel book using Python?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I tried to adapt VBA examples from [How do you get Excel to refresh data on sheet from within VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba), they do not work: sheet.Calculate does nothing, other versions of calculate cannot be found...

Comment: What do you mean by calculate? Recalculate the formulas?

Comment: yes, calculate the results of the formulas (equivalent of F9)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198365/facing-problem-with-xlwt-and-xlrd-reading-and-writing-simultaneously

Comment: what do you think about my answer below?

Comment: I don't know, I've only ever used the xlrd module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a CalculateFull macro progrmmatically and calling it solves the problem, but looks convolutive ...

```
xlmodule = book.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) # http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830 if this line throws an error
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString('Public Sub AnotherCalculateFull() \n\
                                               Application.CalculateFull \n\
                                               End Sub')
```